# I felt relieved as I read it, vindicated, almost personally understood…

Tags: word-meaning

The structure of the phrase "I felt relieved as I read it, vindicated, almost personally understood…" is not very clear to me.

It appears to explain why "I felt relieved", because I read it and almost understood it. The problem for me is the meaning of "vindicated" - "(I) vindicated"? It seems that before reading the book (The End of Faith), the author thought it was guilty to criticize religious moderates who respect other people's different faith; as the author went further in reading it, he understood the book's view and vindicated/proved the author of the book.

I am not sure I am on the right track.

What does "vindicated" mean here?

> The End of Faith articulates the dangers and absurdities of organized religion so fiercely and so fearlessly that **I felt relieved as I read it, vindicated, almost personally understood…** Harris writes what a sizable number of us think, but few are willing to say in contemporary America… This is an important book, on a topic that, for all its inherent difficulty and divisiveness, should not be shielded from the crucible of human reason.

Source: [The New York Times Book Review](https://samharris.org/books/the-end-of-faith/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vindicate (verb) from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vindicate)

- to free from allegation or blame
- (1): CONFIRM, SUBSTANTIATE
  (2): to provide justification or defense for : JUSTIFY
- to protect from attack or encroachment : DEFEND

With the use of "**vindicated**", the author wants to express his feeling of relief and confirmation as his own convictions and beliefs agree with those displayed in the book "The End of Faith".